# Insert <link> and <script> tags and xmlns using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, insert

I have a generated xhtml-file which starts with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Manual</title>
    <meta name="generator" content="DocBook XSL Stylesheets V1.78.1" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="Software logistics, ticket" />
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

Now, I want to add `link` and `script` tags inside the `head` tag and I want to add `"xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"` in the `html` tag. 
I am using the following xsl so far:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" 
        doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
        doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        indent="yes" encoding="iso-8859-1"/>

<xsl:template match="/html">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
          xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/html/head">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"
        href="common/css/screen.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print"
        href="common/css/print.css" />
    <script src="../../common/js/common.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But it does not work. The output should be an xhtml file and I am using xsltproc to apply my xsl sheet to the xhtml input file. Neither the xmlns:ui is added nor the tags are added ... What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that your first two templates do not match anything. They do not match anything, because the elements in the source document are in the `xhtml` namespace - and you must call them accordingly:

First, declare the `xhtml` namespace in your stylesheet element and assign it a prefix:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:x ="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
exclude-result-prefixes="x">
```

With that in place you can do:

```
<xsl:template match="/x:html">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
          xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

You also need to place any new elements within the copied namespace - so your second template needs to look more like this:

```
<xsl:template match="x:head">
    <xsl:copy>
        <x:link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"
            href="common/css/screen.css" />
        <x:link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print"
            href="common/css/print.css" />
        <x:script src="../../common/js/common.js" type="text/javascript"></x:script>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that I have moved the new elements inside the `xsl:copy` instruction, because you said you wanted them inside the `head` tag.